# Calculator protocol specification

Tags: windows-10, protocol-handler

In the Windows settings (default apps by protocol), I saw that the calculator app has registered itself for the calculator protocol:

[image: Calculator protocol]

That means I can use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `calculator://` to open the calculator.

Is there anything else I could to with the calculator protocol?  I am looking for the specification of the calculator protocol. I tried `calculator://4+5` but it didn't give me the result.

As of 2023, the protocol seems to be `ms-calculator://` now:

[image: 2023 update]

Comment: Technically the `+` in `4+5` should be written as `%2B` otherwise it’ll be considered a space. That said, I couldn’t get it to work even when it was properly encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More accurate answer, although it's not positive - you can't currently do anything except opening the calculator with the protocol.

[Source](https://github.com/microsoft/calculator/blob/35f4d7e75ad2ddc99f21ddc248fb537c662f3479/src/Calculator/App.xaml.cs#L98-L106) (last commit from 29th September 2022)

`args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol` checks if we launched the application through the protocol. Then we have this comment:

```
// We currently don't pass the uri as an argument,
// and handle any protocol launch as a normal app launch.
```

That suggests no extra handling of the protocol except launching the app normally. The call of `OnAppLaunch(args, null)` defined in the same file further confirms it - there's no parsing of the URI anywhere in that function.